# ServiceNow dynamic label change

Tags: scripting, servicenow, cmdb

I am currently building a CMBD in ServiceNow and have come across a problem I cannot seem to figure out.  In my database instance table, I would like to be able to add a field to the table that pulls from all of the names of applications I have in my applications table, and then i would like to display both the instance name and the application name in the label for my dependency view like this:

```
Database Instance, Application Name
```

or

```
Database Instance (Application Name)
```

I have managed to set up the application name field by creating a reference in the database instance table but I cannot figure out how to make the label for the database instance objects to display both the instance and the application name.  I know it probably has some scripting behind it but I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label shown in the dependency field is the field where "Display" is set to true. On Configuration Items, when no display field is set, it takes the name field by default.

If you want to keep the name field for the Application's name only, you will have to do the following

- Create an additional field for the display name, u_display_name for example
- Make the field read-only and check it as Display field
- Create an onBefore Business Rule that triggers on the change of the Application or Instance name fields
- Let the Business Rule set the display field as required

See the below screenshot for an example[image]